# Disconnected context was detected while scanning image file

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro, scanning, disconnect

i'm trying to scan file with a feeder scanner in my WPF application, Caliburn Micro and Windows.Device.Scanners. The application works fine at the first attempt to scan, but when i close the view and i reopen that, Visual Studio gave me the error "Disconnected context was detected" after the scan.

```
if (!IsScanning)
{
    ImageScannerScanResult result=null;
    IsScanning = true;

    result= await myScanner.ScanFilesToFolderAsync(ImageScannerScanSource.Feeder, folder).AsTask(cancellationToken.Token, progress);
    if (result.ScannedFiles.Count > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile file = result.ScannedFiles[0];
            System.Drawing.Bitmap Bit = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(file.Path);
            Execute.OnUIThread(() =>
            {
                _Image = Utils.BitmapToBitmapSource(Bit);
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Image);
            });
            IsScanning = false;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            IsScanning = false;
        }
```

And this is the OnDeactivate()

```
protected override void OnDeactivate(bool close)
{
    base.OnDeactivate(close);
    _CurrentScannerDeviceId = null;
    if (scannerWatcher != null)
    {
        scannerWatcher.Added -= OnScannerAdded;
        scannerWatcher.Removed -= OnScannerRemoved;
        scannerWatcher.EnumerationCompleted -= OnScannerEnumerationComplete;

        if (scannerWatcher.Status == DeviceWatcherStatus.Started)
        {
            scannerWatcher.Stop();
        }

        scannerWatcher = null;
    }
    if(cancellationToken!=null)
        cancellationToken.Cancel();
    GC.Collect();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [WIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Image_Acquisition) approach for scanning. I'd rather recommend to use [TWAIN API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWAIN) (in our company we tried both ways, and twain looks better).
There are several .NET twain wrapper libraries:

- [Saraff.Twain](https://sarafftwain.codeplex.com/)
- [TwainDotNet](https://github.com/tmyroadctfig/twaindotnet) (available as NuGet package)
- [NTwain](https://bitbucket.org/soukoku/ntwain) (available as NuGet package)